# Is there a way to immediately exit a hanging connection in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, bash, ssh

I often have SSH connections through Terminal that stop responding (like if I've left it overnight) but when I try to use the dead connection Terminal doesn't respond for several minutes until:

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

Is there a way I can tell bash to immediately disconnect (because I know the connection is dead) without closing/opening a new window?

Comment: Does CTRL+C not work for that?

Comment: Agreed.  CTRL+C should work.

Comment: Should of mentioned that CTRL+C and CTRL+D do not work.

Comment: Control characters only send a signal to the application to be handled by the application. If the connection is dead the character waits to be sent like any other character typed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can type

~.

which ends the SSH connection. Normally it works immediately, but sometimes you may need to do it a few times.

Comment: Worked perfectly first time for me :)